# Mysql count rows in a JOIN table statement, is it possible?

Tags: mysql

Given this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.dogTag, a.dateEdited
FROM dvdpedia a
JOIN dvd_uploads b ON a.dogTag = b.dogTag
JOIN dvd_moderators c ON a.dogTag = c.dogTag
WHERE b.uploader != 9  AND c.moderator != 9
ORDER BY a.dogTag ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

I only want to select the rows from dvd_moderators that appear only once, that is that have been moderated once only and not more and that don't match the userID given (9 in this example).

`dvd_moderators` would look something like this:

```
id    dogTag    moderator
219    2         9
2226   2         7
```

Of course the moderator ID would change for other entries.

Using a COUNT works mostly except when the userID matches the moderator:

```
SELECT  a.dogTag, a.dateEdited, COUNT(c.dogTag) AS moderations
FROM dvdpedia a
JOIN dvd_uploads b ON a.dogTag = b.dogTag
JOIN dvd_moderators c ON a.dogTag = c.dogTag
WHERE b.uploader != 9 AND c.moderator != 9
GROUP BY c.dogTag
HAVING moderations = 1  
ORDER BY a.dogTag ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Then it reports it as being moderated only once (which is a correct query, it is discarding the row that matches moderator = 9 and hence the count is coming out to 1 instead of 2) but incorrect for the purposes I need.

Basically I want the rows that have been moderated only once and that one of those moderators does not match the userID (9 in the example above).

How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Guido over at Sitepoint, this is the soluton he provided. I am putting it here in the hopes it will help someone else in a similar situation:

```
SELECT a.dogTag, a.dateEdited
FROM dvdpedia a
JOIN dvd_uploads b ON a.dogTag = b.dogTag
JOIN dvd_moderators c ON a.dogTag = c.dogTag
JOIN
 (SELECT dogTag
  FROM dvd_moderators
  GROUP BY dogTag
  HAVING count(dogTag) = 1
 ) AS d
ON a.dogTag = d.dogTag
WHERE 1=1 
AND   b.uploader != 9 
AND   c.moderator != 9
ORDER BY a.dogTag ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

And the [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?886639-Mysql-count-rows-in-a-JOIN-table-statement-is-it-possible&goto=newpost) to that post if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.dogTag, a.dateEdited, COUNT(c.dogTag) AS moderations 
FROM dvdpedia a 
JOIN dvd_uploads b ON a.dogTag = b.dogTag AND b.uploader != 9
JOIN dvd_moderators c ON a.dogTag = c.dogTag AND c.moderator != 9
GROUP BY c.dogTag 
HAVING moderations = 1   
ORDER BY a.dogTag ASC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work and gives me the exact same moderations count as my last query above :(